Navbar react tailwind
I am currently working on a React project and need help creating a responsive navbar using Tailwind CSS. Specifically, I am trying to add a shopping cart icon or button to the navbar, where users can click to view their cart items. I would like to understand the best way to implement this using Tailwind for styling and React for functionality.
I have already set up a basic React app and installed Tailwind, but I'm not sure how to structure the navbar with the cart in a way that it looks good and remains responsive across different screen sizes.
Here are a few specific things I'm looking for:
How to structure the navbar with a logo on the left and a cart icon on the right.
How to add a badge to the cart icon showing the number of items.
How to make the navbar responsive, so it adjusts properly for mobile devices.
Any best practices for organizing the component in terms of reusable parts or cleaner code.
If anyone has examples or advice on how to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate it. Code examples or links to resources would be helpful as well!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

<nav className="bg-[#131921] text-white p-4 shadow-lg">
  <div className="container mx-auto flex items-center justify-between">
    <Link to="/Home">
      <img
        src="https://en.saudishopper.com.sa/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Amazon.sa_.png"
        alt="Amazon.sa"
        className="h-10 hover:opacity-80 transition-opacity duration-300"
      />
    </Link>

    <div className="flex-grow mx-4"></div>

    <div className="flex items-center space-x-6">
      <div className="text-right">
        <p className="text-sm font-light">
          Hello, <span className="font-semibold">{user ? user.name : "User"}</span>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div className="relative">
        <Link to="/Cart">
          <FaShoppingCart className="h-8 w-8 text-[#f08804] hover:text-[#f08a04b1] transition-colors duration-300" />
        </Link>
      </div>

      <div className="relative">
        <button
          onClick={logout}
          className="bg-[#f08804] text-white py-2 px-4 rounded-lg hover:bg-[#f08a04b1] transition-colors duration-300"
        >
          Logout
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

);

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
